# Code Redirection With a certain Password/Code

Tags: html, redirect

i want to have it so that when someone enters a code in the box on my website they get redirected somewhere. an example would be:

```
Insert Code:
Placeholder

Redirect to:
../Page3/Page3.html
```

Comment: Can you provide more context or code to support?

Comment: Basically, if i type "Placeholder" in a password box and hit enter, it redirects me to a page.
if i type "Code" It brings me to another page

Comment: Please Include your code.